# How to crop an image outside it's original boundaries

Tags: java, imgscalr

I have an image of a face that's a narrow rectangle and I want to crop a square image centered on the face so that the bounds of the cropped image extend beyond the boundaries of the original image.

Here's an example, the **green** box is the boundary of the original image and the **red** box is the desired boundary of the new image.

How do I perform this "crop" in Java?

[image]

Currently this is what I'm doing, but `imgscalr` wouldn't let me crop outside the bounds of the original image.

```
static BufferedImage crop(BufferedImage bufferedImage, BoundingBox box) {
    int y = box.top as Integer
    int x = box.left as Integer
    int targetWidth = box.width as Integer
    int targetHeight = box.height as Integer

    Scalr.crop(bufferedImage, x, y, targetWidth - 1, targetHeight)
}
```

Comment: Make an image of the size you want and copy part of the original image to it. You'll need to edit your question to explain where you are stuck. Please read [ask].

Comment: The problem is that this isn't cropping, so no _crop_ function will do this for you. the best you can probably do is crop the image to the rectangle defined by the horizontal red and the vertical green, and then copy that to the right position in a new image with the dimensions specified by the red rectangle.

Comment: Looking at the API doc, you might be able to use `crop()` to the red horizontal/green vertical bounding box, and then use `pad()` to pad the image, or maybe first pad, then crop.

Answer (score 1):

Padding the image before cropping solved the problem

```
static BufferedImage pad(BufferedImage bufferedImage) {
    int padding = Math.min(bufferedImage.height, bufferedImage.width) / 2
    BufferedImage paddedImage = Scalr.pad(bufferedImage, padding, Color.WHITE)
    return paddedImage
}
```

Then I cropped the padded image.

Thanks, everyone for the help in the comments.